Laravel Pint: How to make formatting of empty classes and methods the same as non-empty ones?
Here is the code for my pint.json file:
{
  "preset": "laravel",
  "rules": {
    "not_operator_with_successor_space": false,
    "concat_space": {
      "spacing": "one"
    },
    "class_attributes_separation": {
      "elements": {
        "method": "one"
      }
    },
    "array_syntax": {
      "syntax": "short"
    },
    "list_syntax": {
      "syntax": "long"
    },
    "braces": {
      "position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs": "next"
    }
  }
}

The project has this code:
namespace App\Providers;

class SomeClass1
{
    public function register(): void
    {
    }
}

Laravel Pint changes it to this code:
class SomeClass1
{
    public function register(): void {}
}

The same goes for the class. The project has this code:
class SomeClass2
{
}

Laravel Pint changes it to this code:
class SomeClass2 {}

I do not like it. I want the formatting of empty classes and methods to look the same as non-empty ones. How can I prevent Laravel Pint from removing newlines from empty methods and classes?
I tried changing the code in the pint.json file, but it didn't help.

To start off, Laravel pint uses https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer internally, so you'd need to find which cs-fixer rule does this and disable it in your pint.json file
